# Dax Filter the count of If

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a calculated column for Champions. Each year, a team that attains 4 wins in the final round is the champion. Basically, I need a DAX statement that translates to "when a Team in a given year has a count of 4 wins in the final round they are that year's champion"

I just don't know how to do this in DAX. I have tried a summary table to no avail. I know I need to Calculate and Filter but it is the Count of Wins for a given year that is given me trouble. Essentially, the Image below should have a champions column. Ignore the title of this image, it is supposed to say "Count of Finalists"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may show only winner team in table by applying visaul filter using this measure,

```
Is Champion = IF ([Count of champion] = 4 ,"YES","NO")
```

Comment: The Count of Champion is not a measure.

Comment: Than you may filter visual by count of champion > 3 that will just give you winners.

Comment: I asked this on the PBI forums and received this reply which worked:

Champions = VAR cham = CALCULATE(
                                COUNTROWS('Database (2)'),
                                FILTER('Database (2)','Database (2)'[Finalists] = "win"))
                                Return
                                IF(cham = 4, "Champions", Blank())